# What is the equivalent of numpy.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.2, 0.8]) in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, numpy

What is the equivalent of `numpy.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.2, 0.8])` in ruby?

Im trying to make a biased switch in that flips on (output `1`) and off (output `0`) in ruby. The switch is biased and will frequently have an 80% chance of being in the "on" (output `1`) setting when called upon.

The `numpy.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.2, 0.8])` does the job fine in python but im curious what the ruby version is like...

Comment: In the specific case, [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1].sample might work well. Okay, I cheated.. and what is the 5 for? Number of values?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296119/128421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://github.com/fl00r/pickup

A simple example is:

```
require 'pickup'
headings = {
  A: 40,
  B: 20,
  C: 40,
}
pickup = Pickup.new(headings)
pickup.pick
#=> A
pickup.pick
#=> B
pickup.pick
#=> A
pickup.pick
#=> C
pickup.pick
#=> C
```

In your case you have 2 option `1/0` and the probabilities is `20` and `80`. But this solution is also applicable if you have a non binary situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rubys `random` with a ternary without any need for other required things:

```
Random.new.rand(1..100)<81 ? 1 : 0
```

to get a True/False value to get 0 and 1

Comment: `rand <= 0.8 ? 1 : 0`

Comment: @steenslag - yep, works as well  - but I guess it would have to be `rand < 0.8 ? 1: 0` because the upper limit is exclusive? the `rand(1..100)` is inclusive and easier to understand if you are not familar with floats. I would probably go for `r=Random.new` somewhere to get a new random generator and use `r` throughout  the place.

Comment: Patrick, the probability that `rand` will draw a given float between zero and (strictly) one, is something like `1.0/n`, where `n` is the largest float that can be represented in Ruby. Considering the imperfections of any pseudo-random number generator, I think @steenslag is on solid ground (it doesn't matter if `<` or `<=` is used).

Comment: @Cary I am just a ruby noob :) using floats will be fine I guess